# ¿Como obtener datos de un array multi dimensional?

Tags: array, reactjs, arraylist, redux, react-redux

Como puedo obtener datos que tengo dentro de un array, puedo obtener los primeros datos, pero cuando intento sacar el dato que tengo dentro de otro no puedo pongo el codigo

```
const series = {
serie:[
    {
       "id": 1,
       "title": "",
       "predescription": "",
       "poster": "",
        "season":[
            {"name": "lol"}
        ]
    }
]}
```

**Los datos desde el id hasta poster los puedo obtener sin problema, el problema viene cuando trato de sacar el dato de season**

agrego el codigo donde muestro los datos

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import '../../css/styles.css'

export class Series extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    const { serie } = this.props
    const postList = serie.length ? (
        serie.map(serie => {
            return(           
            <div className="contenedor-img ejemplo-1" key={serie.id}>
            <h1>{serie.season.name}</h1>
                <Link to={'/postss/' + serie.id}>
                        <div className="poster">
                            <img src={serie.poster} />
                        </div>
                    <div className="mascara">
                        <h2 className="card-title grey-text">{serie.title}</h2> 
                        <p>{serie.predescription}</p>
                        <a href="#" className="link">Leer mas</a>  
                    </div>
                    
                </Link>
            </div>
            )
        })
    ) : (
        <div className="center">
            <h1>No posts yet</h1>
            <div class="preloader-wrapper big active">
            <div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue-only">
                <div class="circle-clipper left">
                    <div class="circle"></div>
                </div><div class="gap-patch">
                    <div class="circle"></div>
                </div><div class="circle-clipper right">
                    <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
        return (
            <div className="container home ">
                <h2 className="center">Series</h2>
                {postList}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
return{
    serie:state.serie
}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Series)
```

esto se basa en react combinado con redux

Answer (score 1):

Tu propiedad "season" es un *array*, por lo tanto debes acceder iterando sobre el mismo:

```
const seasonName = serie.season[0].name;
```

En tu componente sería algo como:

```
<h1>{serie.season[0].name}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que volver a usar map, en el objeto que quieres retornar.

```
serie.map(serie => {
  return (
    <div>
      { serie.season.map(season => (
        <p>{ season.name }</p>
      )) }
    </div>
})
```

Comment: Cabe resaltar que en este caso si existieran multiples objetos dentro del array se desplegarían varios <p>